# Attempting to assign to a C# 'foreach iteration variable' generates a compile time error. Doing so in a Linq [IEnumerable].ForEach(...) does not. Why?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, runtime

I noticed what I believe to be strange behaviour in C# and Linq today when trying to make a class a bit tidier and remove a for loop, used to initialise an array of strings.

My original code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < tagCount; i++)
    {
        myObj.tags[i] = string.Empty;
    }
```

It is known that values cannot be assigned to the iteration variable in a C# foreach loop. The following, for instance, generates a compile-time error (where myObj is an object which contains an array of strings called 'tags'):

```
    foreach(string s in myObj.tags)
    {
        s = string.Empty;
    }

    Gives: "Cannot assign to 's' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'"
```

But doing the following compiles correctly:

```
    myObj.tags.ToList().ForEach(s => s = string.Empty);
```

My question is why this syntax compiles without any issue?

---

**NOTE: Strange Behaviour - Possible Bug? - Below**

As a follow-up, I think it certainly feel it worth noting that, whilst the Linq method compiles, during run-time, the effect of the command `s=string.Empty` is not seen, nor is a run-time error generated. `string.Empty` can be replaced with any value, and inspection of any of the indices in the `myObj.tags` array will show a null value. Breaking and stepping into the `...ForEach(s=>s=string.Empty)` shows the line being executed as expected, but no change in the value of s.

This struck me as strange behaviour mostly because no error had been generated either - it seemingly just does nothing. Is this by design? An oversight?

Thank you all for any input.

---

(P.S. I am aware of the performance hit of ToList().ForEach(). I just wanted to see if I could remove that for-loop. I am now more interested in the reason behind the behaviour exhibited during compilation and run-time).

Comment: There is no ForEach method in LINQ, the ForEach method you are using is from [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does nothing - but there are lots of cases where that happens in C#. It's not clear where you'd expect it to be an error, or what you'd expect it to achieve. Basically your lambda expression is a shorthand for writing a method like this:

```
static void Foo(string s)
{
    s = string.Empty;
}
```

That's not a useful method, but it's a perfectly valid one. Calling it for each value within the list doesn't make it any more useful.

Assigning back to a value parameter (rather than a `ref` or `out` parameter) and not reading from the parameter again is basically pointless, but valid.

In terms of removing the loop - one thing you could do is write an extension method:

```
public static void ReplaceAll<T>(this IList<T> list, T value)
{
    // TODO: Validation
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Then you could call:

```
myObj.tags.ReplaceAll("");
```

Comment: Hi. And thanks for the reply. I'm not entirely sure where I'd expect the error to be either. Perhaps when trying to assign in the loop (akin to when writing the foreach). Though @Adil Mammadov covers this in his answer. What I'm trying to achieve is initialising the values of the array to something other than null before the object is sent over the network. The libraries I'm working with (Opensplice DDS) do not allow objects with null fields to be sent in their implementation of the DDS standard. And thank you for your solution to removing the loop.

Comment: @cprlkleg: But the lambda expression is just a lambda expression, being converted into a delegate. The compiler doesn't know what `ForEach` is going to do with it. Fundamentally that's one of the benefits of using a language feature rather than a library - the compiler has more understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Thank you. It makes a lot more sense now. I guess I hadn't thought about it a whole lot - and hadn't realised the differences between foreach and the lambda.

Comment: (sorry to restart this) Actually, I'm not sure I do understand. After the lambda executes, the values in tags are all still null, not an empty string. Why was the "s=string.Empty" not seen to have been applied? (I can read back from the myObj.tags directly after executing the lambda and all values in "tags" are still null.

Comment: @cprlkleg: Read my answer again :) The assignment just assigned a value to the parameter. That does nothing. If you'd got the `Foo` method in my answer and written `for (int i =0; i < list.Count; i++) { Foo(list[i]); }` would you expect that to change the content of the list? If so, I think you misunderstand how parameters work in C#.

Comment: Ahh. It makes sense again. Thank you for taking the time to spell it out to me :)